# Checking and Splitting CSV File Content into 2 separate files

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, csv, awk

I have a csv file which looks like this:

```
Docushare Host
locale, created_at, version
en,Wed Feb 21 17:25:36 UTC 2018,07.00.00.C1.609

User
handle, client_data, docCountQuota
User-12,,-2

Document
handle,client_data,cfSpecialWords
Document-13,x,y
Document-14,z,a
Document-11,ab,cd

Collection
handle,client_data,routing_template
Collection-1,asdsad,asdad
Collection-2,xyz, abc
Collection-3,xada, adsad
```

Is there a faster way to split this CSV and produce two separate files for:

```
 Document-13,x,y
 Document-14, z, a
 Document-15, ab, cd
```

And

```
 Collection-1,asdsad,asdad
 Collection-2,xyz, abc
 Collection-3,xada, adsad
```

These two files will be used for a nodejs application which will in turn parse it again to create a final CSV with required Fields.

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following simple `awk` may help you on same:

```
awk -F, '/^Document-/ && NF>1{print > "Document.csv";next} /^Collection/ && NF>1{print > "Collection.csv"}'   Input_file
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now:

```
awk -F, '
/^Document-/ && NF>1{
  print > "Document.csv";
  next
}
/^Collection/ && NF>1{
  print > "Collection.csv"
}
'   Input_file
```

As output it will create 2 output files named `Document.csv` and `Collection.csv` whose contents will be same as shown by you.

Comment: Thank you for helping an old guy trying to learn coding. Thank you! Will read more on AWK too. I didn't know about it. I was trying to do it using javascript but couldn't do it. Thank you! I'll also check if i can have this command line code run on my node app. Like this will run once I click a button. Thank you!